# Coral not found by mdt on Catalina

Tags: macos, macos-catalina, google-coral

I am testing google coral hardware. I followed all the instructions and everything worked fine except if I try

```
mdt devices
```

no device is found. I can connect via serial fine, but not via mdt. I have a Mac with Catalina. I already found few answers on stack overflow, but none work for me.

Anyone any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a solution to the MDT problem, but I manage to activate `ssh` manually. I wrote a blog post to describe it if it can help someone.

http://blog.toelt.ai/coral/2019/12/18/coral_setup_on_catalina.html

I hope it can be helpful.
Umberto

Answer (score 0):

Great question! I was actually using Catalina and ran into this exact same problem. Unfortunately, Catalina has an issue with Mendel.

However, any macOS version under Catalina should do the job.

Comment: Yeah I know. I found a kind of a workaround (see the answer below)... Maybe it can help you too.